# Bootstrap responsive does not work?

Tags: html5, css3

Can anyone master take a look at my template travel website, I'm new in responsive design and have a template to reference. It was coded in responsive way, but when I open it, nothing happen. This is my site www.lacda.vn, could you guys suggestion any error. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a question better suited to Stackoverflow (code-based) but at a glance I can say that much of the code on that site has abandoned the classes that make bootstrap responsive (`class="row"` and `class="spanX"`).